# Adding custom functions to javascript's Array class breaks array declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js

One of my Nodejs project I've added a solution from stackoverflow for finding differences between two arrays.

```
Array.prototype.diff = function (arr2) {
    return this.filter((x) => !arr2.includes(x));
};
```

Until today, everything was working fine but today my personal cli got broken without any reason and I realized that, on array declaration nodejs automatically adds key value pair to array. (key:diff, value:function (arr2)...)

```
    const values = [];
    for (const i in values) {
        console.log(i, values[i]);
    }
    // diff [Function (anonymous)]
```

I've removed the function from other project, upgraded nodejs to higher version but it still adds above key value pair. How can I fix this?

Comment: your `values` inherits the diff property from the prototype. the syntax `const i in values` get all indexed element in your array. Your array acts like a dictionnary.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have fixed it. Previously I have published the npm library which contains the code:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function (arr2) {
    return this.filter((x) => !arr2.includes(x));
};
```

and it brokes all the codes that use my library. Today I've changed the code with

```
const diff = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter((x) => !arr2.includes(x));
```